# Java resource pool

Tags: java, pooling, object-pooling

I have an app that stores data in XML. When user asks for data, XML is parsed into entities, which are then showed to him via something-like-servlet.

My problem is, that after every refresh, something-like-servlet has to process data again and parsing XML is expensive. There is also too much XML's to store all data in memory.

I was thinking about something like resource pooling, where program asks pool, if there is Entity with name **foo** in pool. If there is, **foo** is returned from pool, if not, **foo** is created from XML and saved to pool.

Something like this:

```
Entity entity = null;
entity.setId(id);
for(Entity entityFromPool : pool.getAllEntities()){
      if(entityFromPool.getId().equals(entity.getId())){
            entity = entityFromPool();
            isInPool = True;
}
if(!isInPool){
   entity = getEntityFromXML();
}
```

I have read about **apache object pooling** but if I understand it correctly, I can not store f.e. 5 different entities with it and then ask if entity with particular id exists in pool.

Is there any library that can help with my problem?
Many thanks!

Comment: Try to also look into caching frameworks. (e.g. ehcache, oscache, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to Commons Pool, then you can take a look at the [KeyedObjectPool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/pool2/KeyedObjectPool.html) interface.

> A "keyed" pooling interface.
>
> A keyed pool maintains a pool of instances for each key value.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I want. I'll try it and see.